# PDF reader for iPad that refreshes automatically after changes to the PDF?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, pdf, latex

I am looking for a pdf reader for my iPad Pro, which automatically refreshes the pdf when another app makes changes to the pdf.

I using Vim in a-Shell to edit my LaTeX document and display the pdf next to it. When I use pdflatex to compile the LaTeX-file, I want the pdf reader to automatically show the then new generated pdf.

The only apps I found so far for this are the Readdle-Apps “Documents” and “PDF Expert”, but both require monthly payments after a short trail period and I cannot afford to pay monthly for something I am using regularly but not daily. I am more than happy to make a one-time-payment for it.

Does anybody know such a pdf reader?

Comment: With more apps moving into subscription models to ensure long-term financial stability, this may become challenging. Which apps did you look at which fit the financial requirements but don't offer live updates?

Comment: So far I checked “PDFelement”, “PDF Editor” and “Foxit PDF Editor”. And “Acrobat Reader” does not give you live updates from what I read online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I finally found one myself: “PDF Viewer” from “PSPDFKit GmbH”. It has some subscription model, but only for advanced features that are not necessary for my case.